# How to update riverpod from GoRouter?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-go-router, gorouter

In my `GoRouter`, I retrieve the query params from the URL:

```
builder: (context, state) {
  String q = state.queryParams['q'] ?? '';
  int pageNumberInt = int.tryParse(state.queryParams['page'] ?? '1') ?? 1;
  // Return component...
}
```

I would like, before returning the Widget, to update the state of a provider but how do I get access to "ref" to do something like:

```
ref.watch(searchFieldValueProvider.notifier).update((state) => q)
```

Answer (score 1):

In any case, you need to have access to `Ref` in order to update the provider status. You can pass it as an argument or in a class constructor. It all depends on your architecture.

And, it will be `ref.read(...)` or `ref.refresh(...)` (if we just need to reset the state) that will need to be used.

Comment: Thx but as I use a goRouter, how can I add it to the constructor ? and how to build ref to pass it to GoRouter ?
final roylloRouter = GoRouter(
  routes: [...]

Comment: you can see an example implementation [here](https://github.com/lucavenir/go_router_riverpod).  And check out this [discussion](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/discussions/1357) to pick up some useful ideas.